# Why is Tommy Ricardo so afraid of Pinaco?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-manga

In chapter 19 of *Full Metal Alchemist*, Winry asks Tommy for an apprenticeship after delivering the baby. As she is asking for it, she mentions Pinaco is her grandmother and Tommy becomes extremely vexed and says, "I don't want to remember those painful memories!"

> [image: Tommy being afraid of Pinaco]

Why was he so afraid of Pinaco?

Comment: Aside from the fact that Pinako has the nickname of "Pantheress of Resembool", was quite a crazy party animal in her youth, and is about as badass as old ladies come, I don't think anything was explicitly mentioned in either series or the manga.